# serialize & unserialize functions

Tags: javascript, php, serialization

I have an array that I'm converting into a string using serialize:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin/adminProccess.php",
    type: "get",
    data: $('#idPriv:checked').serialize().replace(/http%3A%2F%2F/g,'#http#')  + '&str=' + 'deleteAdmin',
    success: function(data) {
```

When the code is sending to the php page is in this format:

```
443d77a90e9eb5524fd4e305eb263885:0
```

So, I used the `unserialize` function to return into an array. But I don't why I'm getting a false response;

This is the code I used in the php page:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($idPriv);$i++){
    $test=$_GET['idPriv'][$i];

    $test  = unserialize($test);;
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?I

Comment: In this format, `443d77a90e9eb5524fd4e305eb263885:0`, are you sure? Check : https://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Comment: the "443d77a90e9eb5524fd4e305eb263885" is md5 encoded. I'm trying to send this string to the php page and to unserialize it.
The "443d77a90e9eb5524fd4e305eb263885:0" is what received in the php page after the serialize is being used in the javascript code

Comment: It's worth mentioning this into your question...

Comment: md5 is non-reversible. You can't get the original contents of the string, after md5-ing it.

Comment: I dont want to get the original value. I only want to send the array to javascript (as a string) and to access it has an array in the php code. Thats why i used serialize & unserialize functions

Answer (score 3):

From the [jQuery's manual on `serialize`:](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Serialize a form to a query string that could be sent to a server in an Ajax request.

So what it does is to take some form values and turn them into a *query string* like

```
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3
```

From the [PHP Manual on unserialize:](http://php.net/unserialize)

> Creates a PHP value from a stored representation

That stored representation is unique to PHP and looks something like this:

```
O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}
```

In other words, you are trying to unserialize a query string, whereas PHP can only unserialize strings serialized with PHP's `serialize`.

With that said, the function to *parse a query string* in PHP would be

- [`parse_str` — Parses the string into variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Abridged example from PHP Manual:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz"; 
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is an environment specific process. If you serialize something in Java/PHP/JavaScript/... then it can only be deserialized using the same environment (at least, that's what you should expect).

The best think you can do is serialize your objects to a well known format, for example JSON. Then you could do the following in JavaScript:

```
JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php
    json_decode(myJson);
?>
```

Of course you could choose for another format (XML, comma seperated, query string, ...), the main clue is that you need to serialize/deserialize to a language that can be used by both environments. And JSON is probably the most obvious one (next to a query string).

Comment: I'm trying to get the data from textboxes there where checked.. thats why i used the serialize function. Dunno why, but with JSON.stringify it didnt work.

Comment: If you could give me the code you used to serialize it with JSON, I might be able to help you. You could also choose another format like a plain query string like @Gordon said.